# Checkbox Filter HTML Table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a HTML table which I have made that has some document.ready functions already attached to it the table simply sorts data(tr) by class(.amount) on load and also has paging - the paging technique is using existing HTML.

I'd like to now add a checkbox filter using jQuery if possible, What I'd like to do is filter the table when the checkbox is clicked to only show table rows that have a cell with the id:

```
#free
```

and obviously contain data no upfront cost.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghzch66e/19/

```
        <h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

    <input type="checkbox"> Free Handset

    <table id="internalActivities">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head1</th><th>head2</th><th>head3</th><th>head4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span><br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span><br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span><br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span><br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td><span id="free">No upfront cost</span><br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" id="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" id="seeLessRecords" value="Less">
```

I have made a jsfiddle so you can see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Need to share the code in the question not just a fiddle link

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... so the `free` and `handsetcost` should be classes

Comment: ok that can be easily changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned since ID of an element must be unique, need to use class for `free` and `handset`.

Then in the paging logic use that also to filter the rows like

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var dataRows = [];

  //Create an array of all rows with its value (this assumes that the amount is always a number.  You should add error checking!!  Also assumes that all rows are data rows, and that there are no header rows.  Adjust selector appropriately.
  $('#internalActivities > tbody > tr').each(function(i, j) {
    dataRows.push({
      'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, "")),
      'row': $(this)
    });
  })

  //Sort the data smallest to largest
  dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.amount - b.amount;
  });

  //Remove existing table rows.  This assumes that everything should be deleted, adjust selector if needed :).
  $('#internalActivities > tbody').empty();

  //Add rows back to table in the correct order.
  dataRows.forEach(function(ele) {
    $('#internalActivities > tbody').append(ele.row);
  })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var trs = $("#internalActivities tbody tr");
  var btnMore = $("#seeMoreRecords");
  var btnLess = $("#seeLessRecords");
  var trsLength = trs.length;
  var currentIndex = 3,
    page = 3;

  trs.hide();
  trs.slice(0, currentIndex).show();
  checkButton();

  btnMore.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    trs.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + page).show();
    currentIndex += page;
    checkButton();
  });

  btnLess.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    trs.slice(currentIndex - page, currentIndex).hide();
    currentIndex -= page;
    checkButton();
  });

  function checkButton() {
    var currentLength = trs.filter("tr:visible").length;

    if (currentLength >= trsLength) {
      btnMore.hide();
    } else {
      btnMore.show();
    }

    if (trsLength > page && currentLength > page) {
      btnLess.show();
    } else {
      btnLess.hide();
    }

  }
  $('#filter-free').change(function() {
    var $all = $("#internalActivities tbody tr").hide();
    trs = this.checked ? $all.has('.free') : $all;
    trsLength = trs.length;
    trs.slice(0, page).show();
    currentIndex = page;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

<input type="checkbox" id="filter-free">Free Handset

<table id="internalActivities">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head2</th>
      <th>head3</th>
      <th>head4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
        <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
<input type="button" id="seeLessRecords" value="Less">
```